# Regex Help. String with no spaces, but 5 digit number in center. Extract the number only. PHP

Tags: php, regex

Sample string

`Rpt#_SPACE_MINVTAN<br_SPACE_/>
_SPACE__SPACE__SPACE__SPACE__SPACE_01212_SPACE__SPACE_`

There is a line break at the end of line one. Line two always has 5 spaces, then a 5 digit number, then  two more spaces.... Now there is more random text before what I pasted, and more random after.

The number of _SPACE_ after the customer number must be 2 or more.

I guess what I'm looking for is this:

Find in the middle of a large string `_SPACE__SPACE__SPACE__SPACE__SPACE_012345_SPACE__SPACE_`

Extract the number into a variable.

Comment: Can you give me a sample string? Like, an actual sample string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution for your specific type of string:
where

```
$string = "Rpt#_SPACE_MINVTAN<br_SPACE_/>_SPACE__SPACE__SPACE__SPACE__SPACE_01212_SPACE__SPACE_";
```

I have tested this and it does indeed work.

```
<?php
$text = "Rpt#_SPACE_MINVTAN<br_SPACE_/>_SPACE__SPACE__SPACE__SPACE__SPACE_01212_SPACE__SPACE_";
$text_array = explode("<br_SPACE_/>", $text);
$array1 = explode("_SPACE_", $text_array[0]);
echo $array1[0] . ' and ' . $array1[1];
$number = trim($text_array[1], "__SPACE__");
echo '<br>and ' . $number;
?>

$array1[0] is the 'Rpt#'
$array1[1] is the 'MINVTAN'
$number is '01212'
```

After you have placed this code in your file and seen that it works please remember to check this off as a solution so others know the post is answered. If you have any other questions please feel free to ask; and have a nice day.

Comment: Thanks! I modified yours a little bit, but it works great now. Thanks again!  

    `$text = $value;
    $text_array = explode("<br_SPACE_/>", $text);
    $customer_number = substr($text_array[2], 37,5);
    echo $customer_number;`

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more specific solution please post more specific code or informaion.

But one solution could be:

```
<?php
$trimmed_text = trim($text, "__SPACE__");
?>
```

Comment: The text is actually \_SPACE_ it's not spaces.

Here is the current code I'm testing.

`([_SPACE__SPACE__SPACE__SPACE__SPACE_]\d{5}_SPACE__SPACE_)`

Comment: @user1424232: Alright you meant '__SPACE__' I thought you were just doing that to explain the situation; but either way by changing the string you are using to trim it should work. I posted a revised version above.

Comment: @user1424232: so do you mean those all that your example above is one string, and not two separate strings?

Answer (score 0):

For the string like below with 5 digits in the center and spaces around it,

```
_SPACE__SPACE__SPACE__SPACE__SPACE_012345_SPACE__SPACE_
```

you can use `preg_match()` like below:

```
$string='_SPACE_SPACE....'; //your string here

preg_match('/\s*(\d{5})\s*/',$string,$matches);

print_r($matches); //$matches[1] will have the matched digits
```

EDIT:

As per the OP if the text is actually SPACE_ then the code will be as below:

```
$string='_SPACE__SPACE__SPACE__SPACE__SPACE_12345_SPACE__SPACE_'; //your string here

preg_match('/[SPACE_]*(\d{5})[SPACE_]*/',$string,$matches);

print_r($matches); //$matches[1] will have the matched digits
```

Answer (score 0):

This is ugly:

```
function onlyNumber($str) { 
     $numbers = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
     $icky = array('_','-','#','<','>','/');
     $num = "";
     for($i=0;$i<strlen($str);$i++) { 
            if(!ctype_alpha($str[$i]) && !in_array($str[$i],$icky) && in_array(intval($str[$i]),$numbers,true)) { 
                $num .= $str[$i];
            }
     }
     return trim($num);
}
```